# Start a python script on server from webpage

Tags: python, html, rest, server

Is there a way to start a python script on a server from a webpage?

At work I've made a simple python script using selenium to do a routine job (open a webpage and click a few buttons).

I want to be able to start this remotely (still on company network) but due to security/permissions here at work I can't use telnet/shh/etc or install PHP (which I've read is one way to do it).

I've made simple python servers earlier, which can send/receive REST request, but I can't find a way to use javascript (which I'm somewhat comfortable with) to send from a webpage.
I've found several search results where people suggest AJAX, but I can't manage to make it work

It doesn't have to be anything more than a blank page with a single button on that sends a request to my server which in turn starts the script.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: using something like `Flask` / `Django` / `Pyramid` setting up a `@route` calling you function :)

Comment: What did you use for your "simple python servers earlier, which can send/receive REST request"? It may be easier for you to grasp an answer that take advantage of that prior experience.

Comment: We created some SimpleHTTPServers and socket servers at university back in the days.

They were not perhaps that simple to build, but their functionality was wery simple.

Answer (score 0):

My example is using `Flask`:

Since you dont need just a blank space open the URL and your selenium will run.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/start")
def yourfunction():
    #start whatever you like here
    return #whatever you like to display eg. status / result
```

Reference: [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: Ok, this looks like something that could work. (Allthough it felt like I spent an eternity to get that bit to work on windows).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can get started.
You can try serving your Python script through [CGI](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/webservers.html).

Alternatively you can wrap your script into a web framework, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).
Taking the fact your code is relatively small and does not need to store data in SQL nor interact with the user, you should go with Flask because it's pretty lightweight and well documented on the web.

Comment: I think I will try with Flask, it seems that's the preferred choice by most.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you'd want to write a simple server that returns an HTML form on a GET request and processes that form on a POST request.

For example, a very simplistic but fully working example using [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/):

```
from bottle import get, post, run

from subprocess import check_output

@get('/')
def home():
    return '<form method="post"><input type="submit" value="Click me!"></form>'

@post('/')
def on_submit():
    return "Today's date is " + check_output(['date']).decode()

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

or using just standard library stuffs with http.server, it's the same concept, though there are a little bit more boilerplates:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

from subprocess import check_output

class Handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def html_preamble(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self.html_preamble()
        response = '<form method="post"><input type="submit" value="Click me!"></form>'
        self.wfile.write(response.encode('utf-8'))

    def do_POST(self):
        self.html_preamble()
        response = "Today's date is " + check_output(['date']).decode()
        self.wfile.write(response.encode('utf-8'))

PORT = 8081
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

By all means, since you wrote the Selenium script in Python, you may want to just import the relevant function and call them directly instead of going through a subprocess, just be careful of resource leaks and make sure your function cleans up any resources that doesn't need to be kept between requests.